# How to Send JWT From Web-API to MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

There is a mobile application which is developed via Xamarin. It mainly uses Web-API services to do its job, but at some point, application calls an MVC project, which is different from the Web-API project, but under the same solution.

I set up a Basic JWT authentication for security issues between communication of mobile app and Web-API. Thus, mobile app simply sends a token in header when requesting anything from Web-API.

```
Authorization: Basic eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

The point where I'm stuck is how could I handle that JWT which is sent in header from mobile app to MVC. Should it be included into the URL string which is triggering MVC controller?

I have run into questions which shows how to call a remove service from MVC controller by using `WebClient`, but couldn't see its vice versa.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Should it be included into the URL string"...normally you'd put a token in the "Authorization" header...but it depends what the receiving application is expecting

Comment: why would a mobile app, which uses an api, have to call an mvc application?